# How to create a wider vertical line space between unique footnote items in ConTeXt?

Tags: footnotes, context, line-spacing

In the default setup, footnote text has a uniform vertical line spacing. When I create a footnote spanning multiple lines, those lines, there is x points between those lines in the same footnote and lines in separate footnotes:

```
1 This is some footnote text that

spans multiple lines.

2 This is a second footnote text.

3 This is a third footnote text.
```

Example code:

```
\starttext
    This is some text\footnote{with a footnote with some long text that space more than one line and continues to a new line} and some more text\footnote{with another footnote}.
\stoptext
```

I want to modify the interline space or a gap between the lines so that text from the same footnote, but overflowing to a new line, is grouped much more closely with the text above it:

```
1 This is some footnote text that
spans multiple lines.

2 This is a second footnote text.

3 This is a third footnote text.
```

When I tried adjusting `\setupinterlinespace`, it adjusted the interline space for everything.

How can I adjust the vertical distance between the text of a footnote that overflows to a new line independent of the vertical distance between one footnote and the next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

`\setupnotation[footnote][after={\blank[2*line]}]`